# How to control whether an object is related to a model or not in Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

There are several models that are related to User model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
  # Its fields
```

```
class Model_1(models.Model)
  user = models.OneToOneField('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  # other fields
```

```
class Model_2(models.Model)
  user = models.OneToOneField('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  # other fields
```

```
class Model_3(models.Model)
  user = models.OneToOneField('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  # other fields
```

```
class Model_4(models.Model)
  user = models.OneToOneField('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  # other fields
```

and in the view:

```
def index(request):
    # If the user is related to model one, do something
    # If the user is related to model two, do something
    # If the user is related to model three, do something
    # If the user is related to model four, do something
    # Otherwise return to the home page
```

---

**After the user sends the request to View, how do I determine which of these models it belongs to?**

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just check for the existence of your model in the user instance

```py
class Model_4(models.Model)
  user = models.OneToOneField('User',
                              related_name='model_4',
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def index(request):
    if request.user.model_4 is not None:
        pass  # Do something
```

Comment: If this raises an AttributeError you can always use `hasattr` or `getattr` with this.